# Random walk on set of integers

Tags: self-study, markov-process

im trying to find the matrix and the graph of this markov chain, let $(Y_i)$ a sequence of iid RV in $\mathbb{Z}$ and identically distributed, let $Y_0$ be independent of $(Y_i)$ -idk why they said this could someone explain its effect- now define $X_0 = Y_0$ and $X_n = \sum_{i=0}^n Y_i$ i proved that $(X_n)$ is a markov chain because it only depends on the previous state using $X_{n+1} = X_n + Y_{n+1}$ now im very confused on how to look at the transition matrix of such markov chain .
**EDIT:**
from what i've seen of nicolas proposition , yes thats an infinite walk over the set of integers, but what i dont understand is: by definition the transition matrix is : $(p_{ij})_{i,j \in \mathbb{Z}}$ but since this is an infinite walk the matrix is of infinite dimension?! this is extremely new to me

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: It sounds like you need a more general mathematical definition of a matrix.  Start with an $n$-vector $x:$ that can be defined as a function $x:\{1,2,\ldots, n\}\to\mathbb R$ where $x_i=x(i).$ That extends to *sequences* $a:\{1,2,\ldots,\}\to\mathbb R$ and *bi-infinite sequences* $a:\mathbb Z\to \mathbb R.$ In the same way, an (ordinary) $m\times n$ matrix is a function $X:\{1,2,\ldots,m\}\times\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\to\mathbb R$ where $X_{ij}=X(i,j).$ A *bi-infinite (real) matrix* is a function $P:\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z\to\mathbb R.$

Comment: Finally, when each row and each column of a bi-infinite matrix $P$ has only a finite number of nonzero entries, the sums involved in the (usual) definition of the matrix product are all finite sums, so you don't have to be concerned about convergence.  Given any other bi-infinite matrix $Q$, we have $$(PQ)_{ij}=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z} P_{ik}Q_{kj}$$ for all integers $i,j,$ with a similar formula for $QP.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your matrix will look as follows,
[image]

Notice, this matrix is infinite in all directions. The reason is that $\mathbb{Z}$, the integers, is an infinite set extended in both directions. Therefore, the transition matrix will be determined by $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$, one for the rows, and one for the cols. Furthermore, if you are currently located at at the integer $i$, then you can only move to $i+1$ or $i-1$ with equal probabilities. Therefore, you see a $0$ with two $\frac{1}{2}$'s on each side of it.

(**Mistake:** The "first" row should be shifted to the left two steps. I am just too lazy to fix the image, and I am sure you can figure out what it means.)

Comment: understandable thank you so much!